# What does 'cut each other off' mean?

Tags: meaning, idioms

What does 'cut each other off' mean when it is in the context of driving or walking?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*To cut someone off* is to force your way in front of someone else moving in the same direction, forcing that person to slow down or swerve to avoid you.

*To cut each other off* is simply the same idiom used reciprocally, indicating that two people are constantly jostling each other trying to get ahead.

Comment: Not necessarily the same direction; an aggressive left-turner can cut off oncoming traffic, for instance.

Comment: +1 So I see you've driven in Massachusetts.

Comment: "To cut each other off" is also not necessarily physical. It can mean to interrupt someone while they are speaking.

Comment: In my (UK) dialect, we call the aggressive driving context *cutting up*. To *cut someone off* is more normally associated with severing communications (anything from interrupting while speaking/hanging up phone to permanently disowning/socially shunning).

Comment: Around my neck of the woods we use the variant "to cut someone _up_" when we're referring to the driving, although _cut off_ is still used when referring to interruptions.

Comment: Interesting. *Cut up* in my region means to crack jokes and goof off.

Comment: @Kit, I've also heard a different usage of _cut up_, as a verb to mean ["badly distressed"](http://www.google.co.uk/search?rlz=1C1AVSA_enGB430GB430&aq=f&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=cut+up#hl=en&rlz=1C1AVSA_enGB430GB430&q=cut-up&tbs=dfn:1&tbo=u&sa=X&ei=UOgyTpX0HMi7hAebv_SICw&ved=0CBcQkQ4&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=73d4a0b2ffe0e558&biw=1680&bih=925). I think this may be an Americanism, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @AndyF Yes, I've heard that, but "broken up" would be more common in my area.

Comment: @Kit: What a language! ;)

Answer (score 2):

[Cut off](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/cut+off) in this phrase is used in the sense of to interrupt or to stop something.

"To cut each other off" in the context of driving is a little odd because usually one person cuts someone else off, meaning that one person's actions interrupt the other person's driving.

For example, as @MonicaCellio said, in the situation where someone turns left across a lane of traffic in a manner that forces the oncoming driver to brake or swerve could be described as "cutting someone off."

So "cutting each other off" while driving would mean that a sequence of cutting off was going on, with Driver A cutting off Driver B, then Driver B cutting off Driver A.

This applies equally to walking, provided that one person's actions interrupt another person's trajectory.

Answer (score 1):

To "cut someone off" in general is to make them have to quickly change course. This can be on the road by swerving in front of them, on the water in a similar fashion, or in a conversation by interrupting or interjecting. A different but related meaning is more literal; a barman can "cut off" a patron who's had too many drinks, refusing to serve them any more, or a father or financial supporter can "cut off" the flow of money to a person who is wasting money or otherwise misbehaving.

If two people are "cutting each other off", it's most likely the first meaning; two people are jockeying for position on the road or in the water by making maneuvers that force the other person to maneuver away to avoid a collision.